# Iframe vue not loading inside of frame

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a Vue app with links and an iframe inside. The base target is set to the iframe but on IOS (Chrome & Safari) it loads the page in a new tab and not inside of the iframe.

```
<base target="gameFrame">
<div id="app">
<a target="gameFrame" href="/example.php">
<iframe :src="Source" name="gameFrame" frameborder="0" v-model="iFrame" id="iframeMain"></iframe>
</div>
```

How would I go about fixing it? I've literally tried everything I can think of.

Comment: Please give us an idea of what you've tried so far "`I've literally tried everything I can think of`" as this may help us narrow down the possibilities

Comment: For instance, add `sandbox="allow-top-navigation allow-scripts allow-forms"` to your iframe and see if the issue persists

Comment: You could also just chuck `rel=”noopener noreferrer”` on your `<a>` tag